# Cut a translucent square in a texture

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

How to remove (cut-out) a transparent rectangle in a Texture, so that the hole will be translucent.

On Android I would use the Xfermodes approach:

[How to use masks in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115732/how-to-use-masks-in-android)

But in libgdx I will have to use opengl. So far I almost achieved what I was looking for, by using the the glBlendFunc  From this nice and very helpful [page](http://www.andersriggelsen.dk/glblendfunc.php) I learend that

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ZERO, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

should  solve my problem, but I tried it out, and it did not quite work as expected:

```
batch.end();
batch.begin();
//Draw the background
super.draw(batch, x, y, width, height);
batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_ZERO,
        GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

//draw the mask
mask.draw(batch, x + innerButtonTable.getX(), y
        + innerButtonTable.getY(), innerButtonTable.getWidth(),
        innerButtonTable.getHeight());

batch.end();
batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA,
        GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
batch.begin();
```

It is just making the mask area plain black, whereas I was expecting transparency, any ideas.

This is what I get:

[image: Mask will be drawn black]

This is what I expected:

[image: Mask area should be transparent]

Comment: Do you have a piece of code for us please? Will be better for understanding your question.

Comment: hmm well I thought about some snippet but I have no approach so far, hence I hoped to that a generic question is more usefull. But I will document my afford so far.

Comment: I get the plain-black-mask effect from the `glblendfunc.php` site for those `setBlendFunc` parameters.  Can you attach a screenshot either of what you're getting or what you want? (Also, note at the `glblendfunc.php` site the "foreground" is the same size as the "background" so the full-alpha of the foreground is applied to the entire background.)

Comment: I got that effect too, but I thought that the background was black. I added the expected and the current status.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/50671/cut-a-translucent-square-in-a-texture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by using the stencil buffer:

```
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
batch.end();
//disable color mask
Gdx.gl.glColorMask(false, false, false, false);
Gdx.gl.glDepthMask(false);
//enable the stencil
Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_STENCIL_TEST);
Gdx.gl.glStencilFunc(GL20.GL_ALWAYS, 0x1, 0xffffffff);
Gdx.gl.glStencilOp(GL_REPLACE, GL_REPLACE, GL_REPLACE);

batch.begin();
//draw the mask
mask.draw(batch, x + innerButtonTable.getX(), y
        + innerButtonTable.getY(), innerButtonTable.getWidth(),
        innerButtonTable.getHeight());

batch.end();
batch.begin();

//enable color mask 
Gdx.gl.glColorMask(true, true, true, true);
Gdx.gl.glDepthMask(true);
//just draw where outside of the mask
Gdx.gl.glStencilFunc(GL_NOTEQUAL, 0x1, 0xffffffff);
Gdx.gl.glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP);
//draw the destination texture
super.draw(batch, x, y, width, height);
batch.end();
//disable the stencil
Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_STENCIL_TEST);
```